# Why mongostat is not defined?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, mongodb, stat

On our Windows 7 x64 machine, we've got `mongod` up and running:

[image: mongod up and running]

But when we try to use `mongostat`, it says it's not defined. Why is it so?

[image: mongostat is not defined]

> Btw, rest all the other queries are working fine.

Are there any specific configurations which needs to be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because `mongostat` is not a command you run from the `mongo` shell, rather it is a separate executable `mongostat.exe`.

Hence you need to run it from it's own command line as you did `mongod.exe` and `mongo.exe`.